# convergence rate of Pearson correlation matrix

Tags: probability, correlation, confidence-interval, convergence, bounds

I posted recently a related question about the convergence rate of a Pearson correlation coefficient, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168224/convergence-rate-of-pearson-correlation).

Now, I am interested in the matrix version.

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_N \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be correlated random variables.
Let $\hat{\rho}(X_i,X_j)$ be the estimated correlation between $X_i$ and $X_j$ from a sample of size $T$.

I derived (cf. [the previous post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168224/convergence-rate-of-pearson-correlation)) the following tail bound.

For $t > 0$,

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\hat{\rho}(X_i,X_j) - \rho(X_i,Y_j)\right| \geq t \right) \leq \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2}T \left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{2t}{1-\rho}} + 1 + \frac{t}{1-\rho} \right) + \ln 2 \right\}$$

Now, I wish a rather sharp tail bound for

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{ij} \left|\hat{\rho}(X_i,X_j) - \rho(X_i,Y_j)\right| \geq t \right)$$

An obvious one is

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{ij} \left|\hat{\rho}(X_i,X_j) - \rho(X_i,Y_j)\right| \geq t \right) \leq N^2 \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2}T \left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{2t}{1-\rho}} + 1 + \frac{t}{1-\rho} \right) + \ln 2 \right\}$$

Can we do better?

My guess is that we can leverage the correlation between the (correlation) coefficients to improve this bound.

There are some results for "[simultaneous confidence interval estimation](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177728912)", but I do not know if it can be applied here.

Comment: Would Wishart distribution help?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am aware that there are concentration bounds for the covariance matrix in spectral norm (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5860.pdf) but I need bounds for the sup norm.

Comment: " we can leverage the correlation between the (correlation) coefficients to improve this bound." - what is the intuition behind this thought?

Comment: Just meant that we may obtain a better bound, for instance in spectral norm it is the case (a factor $N$ instead of $N^2$).
In my case, I am considering block-diagonal correlation matrix with uniform correlation $\rho$ inside each block (clusters).

Comment: I would start with $N=3$, instead of the general case $N$. In some diff geometry problems $N=2$ is not extendable to a general case, but $N=3$ is.